Getting error Invalid provisioning profile signature in transporter while iOS app upload
Getting error while trying to upload production iOS build using transporter.
ERROR ITMS-90165: "Invalid provisioning profile signature. The provisioning profile included in the com.app.APPBUNDLE bundle [“Payload/APPNAME.app”] can't be used to upload apps to App Store Connect until it has a valid signature from Apple."
I already tried below things

Remove old provisioning profile. and install new one
Re-generate the profile
Re-generate all certificates again

my xcode version is 15.4 and transporter version is 1.2.2

We are also seeing the same issue. Our profiles and signing are valid, and we can infer that because after retrying with iTMSTransporter we are able to get the same bundle that was rejected, accepted. We have filed FB15571666

Hi @theraven i just update the transporter and its works

Updating the transporter app also worked for me.

@MitulBhadeshiya I am using circle CI macOS instance to build and upload apps using fastlane. How can I update ITMSTransporter in circleCI instance?

In my case I was using the transporter application to push the build to app store. I tried many things but there was no any solution
Than after I update the transporter application and its works

You sava my day guys ! I update the transporter application ,everything was ok
@Mitul Bhadeshiya

Please consider using a comment for this kind of reply.

I had the same issue, in my case we are using Fastlane to deploy, I had ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD = true in my fastfile due to prior iTMSTransporter issues, fixed by removing force uploading
